# Are finitely presented modules finitely presentable?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, presentable-categories

Over a ring $R$ we have a notion of finitely presented module, namely:

> **Definition 1** A module $F$ is finitely presented if there are $m$, $n$ positive integers such that $R^m\to R^n\to F\to 0$ is exact.

However there is also the (more general)

> **Definition 2** If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with arbitrary direct limit, an object $F$ is finitely presentable if $\mathbf{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(F,-)$ commutes with direct limits.

I have read from multiple sources that these definitions are equivalent. I was able to find a proof of $1\Rightarrow 2$ in [Commutative Coherent Rings](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9783540511151) **Theorem 2.1.5(2)**. Can somebody point to a reference or at least the idea of the proof?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111472/reference-request-compact-objects-in-r-mod-are-precisely-the-finitely-presented

Comment: see the book: Adamek and Rosicky, *Locally presentable and accessible categories* (esp. Example 1.2(5) and Cor 3.13)